# What is the word for knowing how to use something (phone, car, etc), but not understanding how it works?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word which encapsulates the above concept. An example: when someone knows how to use their phone, but doesn't understand how to take it apart, put it together, etc.

Comment: Perhaps they have *an operational understanding*.

Comment: on the internet they might be called a [***(l)user***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luser)

Comment: A *basic user* ?

Comment: An end user might know how something works, but they don't have to.

Comment: functional understanding

Comment: "Normal life", I suspect.

Answer (score 3):

We may use the simplistic term :

•WORKING KNOWLEDGE — the adjective can be made WORKABLE if need be.

But I would love to use - BASICS - in all these situations.

Comment: Yes; almost certainly the best answer. But ELU requires that even correct answers should have supporting references, linked and attributed, where this is reasonable. Wiktionary, for instance, is ideal here.

Comment: I value your profundity. Write something by way of comment. That would be fine!

Comment: Just add a linked and attributed definition from say Wiktionary, with an example sentence if they provide one.

Answer (score 2):

There is a relevant term, but it refers to the object being used, not to the user. In your example, the person is using their phone as a **black box**. As Wikipedia says,

> a black box is a device, system or object which can be viewed in terms of its inputs and outputs [...], without any knowledge of its internal workings.

Comment: It's usually used in an academic rather than an everyday register.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to dismantle and/or repair much of the technology I use - mechanical and electrical.  In these instances I would describe myself as a *consumer*.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it *superficial understanding*, which suggests that there is a lot that is not understood (the inner workings of the device).

Answer (score 0):

In the academia we term what you are asking for as **Recipe knowledge**. Vennix, J. (2019) defines recipe knowledge as "knowledge about fairly routine  issues that we use every day in our (social) discourse." Moreover, Vennix gives an example of making a phone call without being an expert in how telecommunication works.

Comment: Schu¨tz (1964) apparently coined the term 'recipe knowledge', defining it as 'culturally learned formulas that are automatically activated and remain unquestioned as long as nothing unforeseen happens'.  He actually used it to describe, in the main, traditional practices that _didn't_ actually work (eg rubbing a sick child's body with elephant dung) but seemed not to delay a normal healing process and obviously gave some ill-founded peace of mind to families. // '[The] academia' is far too broad-brush. Linguists often have interesting discussions. Debates. Bunfights. Scientists too.